# React env variables with .env

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I'm trying to follow docs on adding env variables from react-create-app without success:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables

[image]

- inside root of the document I have a ".env" file (default .env properties)
- .env file contains only one variable 'REACT_APP_API_HOST=http://localhost:8080'
- trying to access process.env inside my app (created with create react app) gives me undefined

This is app.js where I'm trying to access process.env without success.

I can't access process.env inside the code. Is there any working example on how to do it?

Comment: Is NODE_ENV defined in your path?

Comment: No, but .env as a default is defined.

Comment: Also, tried with defined NODE_ENV and still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah weird! Are you able to access any other variable using process.env by exporting it in bash profile?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: After you add new `.env` variable, make sure to restart yarn. Also, your custom .env variables should start with `REACT_APP_`

Answer (score 16):

You can use .env file on root.

- `start: react-scripts start` - uses `.env.development`
- `build_staging: "set REACT_APP_ENV=staging & react-scripts build"` - uses `.env.staging`
- `build: "react-scripts build"` - uses `.env.production`

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json you will eventually have to add `NODE_ENV=development` at your start script. E.g. `NODE_ENV=development && node scripts/start.js` for the ejected `create-react-app` and `NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start` for the unejected one.

Edit: Apparently `NODE_ENV=development` is not required since it is already hardcoded when you run the `start` or `build` script. Per the docs your custom environment variables should have the following format `REACT_APP*` as you have already done.

A snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Issue was that I was trying to read it while in debug mode by watching variables. For some reason, it does not work. By simply console logging it, it works.