# How to set PUBLIC_URL in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

How to set PUBLIC_URL in create-react-app?

I use cross-env so that I'm goona set PUBLIC_URL like below.

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:8080 react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts-ts"
```

And console.log(process.env) show me the right result about NODE_ENV, dev.
But PUBLIC_URL is just ' ' that default value.

how can i set PUBLIC_URL? I need two PUBLIC_URL for development and production environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389288/react-env-variables-with-env I hope this will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start loads webpack.config in development configuration, which ignores `PUBLIC_URL`. It starts a development server that serves files at host root. If you need to change port for the development server, use [`PORT`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) instead.

(Original answer fixed, see comments)

Comment: In development (localhost), PUBLIC_URL is ignored, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/. Also, it seem you are confusing PUBLIC_URL with homepage in `package.json`.

Comment: Hi, @ambroise. Thanks for the comment. There indeed are some errors in my answer. PUBLIC_URL overrides homepage, but they are not treated equal. Homepage has only path used while PUBLIC_URL stays as it is with host, if it was present. Actual problem was perhaps that development server serves the app at root. The port from PUBLIC_URL is not used to change where the developmen server listens for connection.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier: It seems now it's used also on DEV (documented in that doc page). I just tested and it works. It makes sense, it may be useful also in DEV.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my experience on this issue:

create-react-app or CRA system sets the

> %PUBLIC_URL%

variable from **.env** file in the root of the application folder, next to file `package.json`.
There is no need to use `PUBLIC_URL` in development configuration, in my experience the app runs just fine in development setting. Running

```
yarn build
```

on a CRA-initialized React application will set the `PUBLIC_URL` variable according to the `.env` file contents. What the `.env` file should contain then?

No need for brackets or braces, just

`.env` file contents:

> `PUBLIC_URL=https://yourdomain.whatever/subdirectory`

for example, if your application is served from `/public_html/subdirectory`.

Additionally, CRA does not support the `homepage` keyword in its `package.json` file, so it can be removed and use `.env` file in the root instead.

Comment: This answer has more thorough contemplation on this setting: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686149/cant-build-create-react-app-project-with-custom-public-url]

Comment: The CRA documentation specifically states to set homepage in package.json in order to deploy on github pages ergo your statement in regard to the usage of the homepage keyword is incorrect.

Comment: so, just .env as the file name ?

Comment: yup, .env so its hidden.  Why would you want to hide a config file that affects your whole project.  There's also .env.development.local and .env.production.local