# environment variable undefined in react js

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to get the environment variable from .env file, I have followed all steps
but don't know why it's showing an undefined value

*.env file*
`REACT_APP_NAME=user`

*in React*
`console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_NAME);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React env variables with .env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389288/react-env-variables-with-env)

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure that the donenv package is installed (`npm install dotenv`)
- Ensure the .env file is in the root directory
- Make sure the following code is present in your main file:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

The import statement in the above code may need to be adjusted based on what stack you're using. I'm assuming this is node, since you haven't provided any details. Comment and let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @SHAHIL Thanks, if my solution worked don't forget to accept the answer :)